# Mysql RAM usage is high

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I am using MariaDB gallera cluster with 5 nodes, Database Version   10.0.23-MariaDB-1~trusty-wsrep-log(mariadb.org binary distribution, wsrep_25.11.r21a2415)
Vendor: mariadb
ClusterControl UI version:  1.3.0.1393
ClusterControl CMON Version:    1.3.0.1242
CMON API Version:   1.3.0.183

All nodes are 60GB of RAM, one of the server consumes more ram usage at the same time other 4 nodes are acting fine.

```
maria2-| success | rc=0 >>
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           60G        28G        31G       4.1M       317M        12G
-/+ buffers/cache:        16G        43G
Swap:          19G         0B        19G
Total:         80G        28G        51G

**maria1-** | success | rc=0 >>
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           60G        46G        **13G**       4.0M       312M       7.3G
-/+ buffers/cache:        38G        21G
Swap:          19G         0B        19G
Total:         80G        46G        33G

maria4- | success | rc=0 >>
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           60G        22G        37G       4.0M       284M       6.7G
-/+ buffers/cache:        15G        44G
Swap:          19G         0B        19G
Total:         80G        22G        57G

maria3- | success | rc=0 >>
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           60G        23G        36G       4.0M       314M       7.0G
-/+ buffers/cache:        15G        44G
Swap:          19G         0B        19G
Total:         80G        23G        56G

maria5- | success | rc=0 >>
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           60G        22G        37G       4.0M       284M       6.7G
-/+ buffers/cache:        15G        44G
Swap:          19G         0B        19G
Total:         80G        22G        57G
```

How to reduce the RAM usage in mariadb1 server?

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Are you writing to all nodes, or is `maria1` somehow 'different'?  Do you have any extra tools on that node?  Same my.cnf?  Have they all been running the the same length of time?  Has an SST occurred, if so, which was the "donor"?  How big is the gcache?  innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Answer (score 0):

A guess...  You have about 20GB of data+index; `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 40G`; and, for some reason, maria1's buffer_pool filled out to full size but the rest did not.

A guess on top of the guess...  A huge query hit mariadb1, did lots of index changes, redo, undo, etc, but then either rolled back or did not send (via Row Based Replication) all the temporary stuff that it took to perform the query.

Comment: gcache is 4G
I am writing to all nodes
my.cnf is same in all servers.
SST is rsync.
Innodb bufferpool size 40GB